# Banno API - Which claims/scopes are needed to get an external unmasked account number?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Through the Banno API, we are attempting to get an authenticated user's external linked accounts in order to allow them to create a transfer in another system.

We are able to successfully get the list of external accounts with masked numbers using the `/users/{userId}/transfers/accounts/external` API.

We are then allowing the user to choose one of the accounts, and before we go to create the transfer, we are calling the `/users/{userId}/transfers/accounts/external/{externalTransferAccountId}/number` API to resolve the full account number.  However, this endpoint is returning the following response:

`{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"user not permitted to access resource"}`

We are using the same credentials/token for both calls, so my assumption is that we're missing a claim or scope that we need to access this information.  As far as I know, we already have the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/accounts` claim enabled for our account, and we are requesting the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/transfers.unmaskednumber.readwrite` scope, which is the only scope listed on the API documentation.

**Are there other claims/scopes we need to successfully call this API?**

The client ID for our test account: `50e62270-babe-4876-aebf-fafb77ab8d29`

We are using the "v0" version of the API.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Corrected docs on scope needed to access the endpoint

It looks like we had a mistake in the docs. Thank you for pointing this out!

The correct *scope* to include your auth URL should be `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/transfers.unmaskednumber.readonly`.

We've updated the docs with that change (you may have to refresh your browser cache): https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/transfers/external-transfer-accounts/#/ExternalTransferAccount%20Modification/get_users__userId__transfers_accounts_external__externalTransferAccountId__number

#### FYI on scopes vs claims

Separately, the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/accounts` is a *claim* which isn't about accessing API endpoints but instead getting data in the *Identity Token*.